# what is codeigniter's load->model third arguments?

Tags: codeigniter

in codeigniter, when loading a model there is a third Boolean argument.
should it always be true?
what is its best practice? does it matter if loading multiple models in one controller function?

thanks allot!

Comment: Have a look at the CI user-guide: [click](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#conn)

Comment: i already read it, but it does not answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the CI documentation:

> "You can tell the model loading function to auto-connect by passing
>   TRUE (boolean) via the third parameter, and connectivity settings, as
>   defined in your database config file will be used..."

You can read more about it here: [Connecting to your Database](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#conn)

The third argument should be set to true, if you wish the model to automatically connect, otherwise you may get a database error.

Comment: thanks, i already read it, but it does not answer my question

Comment: sorry about that, i forgot to answer your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: ok, so it should always be true, and if i load multiple models in one controller function should i put true in all?